# Create Manual Order for another customer

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

Is there any way for an admin to use the Manual gateway and create an order for another customer in the system? Or is the only option for the admin to Log In as User feature and go through the checkout process that way?

I'm thinking of either a plugin or front-end templates protected by `{% if currentUser.can('accessCp') %}` where the admin can select customers from a drop-down, select a product from another drop-down, then checkout using the Manual Gateway.

My situation is I have a labor request product. My client sells digital PowerPoint files of church hymnal songs. A customer can purchase a "Song Request" if the customer needs a song that my client has not created yet. So the sale is on the request. But once the product is made available, I need a way to give that product to the customer.

I don't think there is anyway to edit an order, so is there anyway to manually create a new order? Maybe there is a way I can use guest checkout with the customer email address, but still stay logged in as the admin?

However, this note from the sample `shop\checkout\index.html` template seems to indicate that you can't manually set the email address to someone else if you are already logged in, yourself.

> {#
>               Setting the guest email address on the guest customer and order.
>               This will have no affect if the user is currently logged in as the cart uses the currentUsers email address.
>               #}

---

Is there any way to edit the Order Options after a product has been purchased? If I could assign during the checkout `{{ item.options.ProductId}} = 0`, then after the product is uploaded, I could just edit that Option to match the new product (or variant) id and query that for the customer on their account page.